Suma acumulada de una columna en pandas
Tengo un dataframe parecido al siguiente
MERCADO SUBMERCADO  CLASE   INVENTARIO      NUEVO     SUMA
CDMX    A-1         A       1500            0         FALSE
CDMX    A-1         A       1500            0         FALSE
CDMX    A-1         A       1500            0         FALSE
CDMX    A-1         A       1500            0         FALSE
CDMX    A-1         A       NA              2000      TRUE
CDMX    A-1         A       NA              0         FALSE
CDMX    A-1         A       NA              400       TRUE
CDMX    A-1         A       NA              0         FALSE

Lo que estoy buscando es aplicar un ffill() para la columna "INVENTARIO" pero cuando haya un valor TRUE en la columna "SUMA" se haga una sumatoria de los valores de "INVENTARIO" y "NUEVO" y aplicar nuevamente un ffill() con el ultimo valor de "INVENTARIO", y cuando vuelva a ver otro TRUE haga una sumatoria nuevamente
df_predicciones.loc[df_predicciones['SUMA'] == True,'INVENTARIO'] = df_predicciones['INVENTARIO'].ffill() + df_predicciones['NUEVO']
Intente hacerlo con el codigo de arriba, pero no se actualiza el ffill() con el nuevo valor
El resultado que me gustaría obtener sería algo como lo siguiente
MERCADO SUBMERCADO  CLASE   INVENTARIO      NUEVO     SUMA
CDMX    A-1         A       1500            0         FALSE
CDMX    A-1         A       1500            0         FALSE
CDMX    A-1         A       1500            0         FALSE
CDMX    A-1         A       1500            0         FALSE
CDMX    A-1         A       2500            2000      TRUE
CDMX    A-1         A       2500            0         FALSE
CDMX    A-1         A       2900            400       TRUE
CDMX    A-1         A       2900            0         FALSE


Encontre la siguiente respuesta
Aplicar por primera vez el ffill()
df['INVENTARIO'] = df['INVENTARIO'].ffill()

Iterar sobre el DataFrame para actualizar los valores de INVENTARIO cuando SUMA es True
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df.loc[i, 'SUMA']:  # Si SUMA es True
        df.loc[i, 'INVENTARIO'] = df.loc[i-1, 'INVENTARIO'] + df.loc[i, 'NUEVO']  # Actualizar INVENTARIO 

Aplicar nuevamente el ffill para llenar después de la última suma
df['INVENTARIO'] = df['INVENTARIO'].ffill()

